# Android adapter populated by Retrofit callback

Tags: android, android-adapter, retrofit

I have a Navigation Drawer which has an adapter to populate a ListView with some data.  I'm using Retrofit to make an API call to get the data, and utilizing the callback methodology.  However, I'm getting an error within the adapter when the getCount method is called because the callback isn't done yet.  Obviously there's an architecture issue I'm running into here, so I'd love to hear any ideas to improve this.

```
private class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context _ctx;
private List<Foo> _foo;

public NavigationDrawerAdapter(Context ctx) {
    _ctx = ctx;
    setupFoo();
}

private void setupFoo() {
    SharedPrefsHelper prefs = new SharedPrefsHelper(_ctx);
    String userID = prefs.getItem("userID", "");

    ApiManager.getFooService(_ctx).getFoo(userID, fooCallback);
}

Callback fooCallback = new Callback<List<Foo>>() {
    @Override
    public void success(List<Foo> foo, Response response) {
        _foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "Could not get foo: "  + e.getMessage());
    }
};

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // This will throw NullPointerException because _foo isn't populated yet
    return _foo.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually works for me:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return _foo == null ? 0 : _foo.size();
}
```

returns 0 if the list of elements is null, otherwise it returns the size.

This is because we know that when _foo is empty, the size is 0 because there is nothing in your list if it is null.

also:

```
 @Override
public void success(List<Foo> foo, Response response) {
    _foo = foo;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Any time you make changes to the backing data of an adapter, you must call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  And thanks for the code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

In your `setupFoo()`, you should initialize `_foo` like `_foo = new ArrayList<Foo>()`.

Then, when the callback returns data, after replacing "old" `foo` data with new data in the `success` method, call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) to let `BaseAdapter` know there's new day available.